# Embedded Signing without using Template

Tags: docusignapi

I have following scenario:

1. User A of the my web application generations the document using my web application.
2. User A then wants to send this document for eSignature to an external user using email.  This external user receives email with docu sign link and then views and signs the document.
3. User A then wants a URL to sign the same document by remaining in my web application.  So instead of using docusign email feature to email document link to himself/herself, User A would like to use the logged in web application to view and sign the document.

I was looking at Docusign's Embedded Signing feature which requires a Template.  Can I follow above 3 steps without using Template?  If yes, please let me know how and steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

embedded signing does not require a template and you can definitely do this.  There are two modes for this.  1) If your online user is a DocuSign user and you have their credentials (because you are using their DocuSign account) or 2) You include a clientUserId value in the signer information.

The second one is the most common and creates a "captive signer."  In either case you can get the "Recipient View" for that signer (a URL) and embed it in your website.

This process is completely separate from whether a template is used or not.  However, that embedded signer must be added to the envelope before the first person signs.